# do web gardens have client affinity

Tags: iis, web, web-garden

I have a situation where my web garden is not using all the processes it can use. Is there some sort of client affinity with web garden, that each client will route to the same w3wp.exe worker?

Comment: Looks like there is a client affinity based on some tests